# Clear Application Cache on ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cache

I want to clear a specific system application's cache — Calendar & Calendar Storage. How do I do it in **ICS**?

I've stopped the running app:

[image]

but cannot find the Clear data / Clear cache like before:

[image]

I'm on a **Nexus S** and I prefer a way to do it natively, without needing to install an app just for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see Calendar and Calendar Storage in my "All apps" list in Settings.

[image]

If I open either of them, I also see the old, familiar Clear Data and Clear Cache buttons.

[image]

Comment: So bottom line, I couldn't see those buttons because I was accessing the apps via the **Running Apps** section, instead of the **All Apps** one...